# R packages - Should I mount /usr/share/R/library

Tags: linux, networking, centos, nfs

We have a small cluster of linux machines (~15) with up to 20 users. Over the last few years we have written a few basic R scripts for doing basic statistical analysis. The problem I have had as a newbie system administrator is package management. Currently if someone writes a new script which requires a new package this package needs to be installed on all machines for all users. This seems like a rather caveman strategy (we also do this for python and perl modules). I am currently upgrading our operating systems from rhel5 to CentOS6 and would to do things properly.

Here are my initial thoughts?

In R on the first machine `margay` (which has CentOs6 running)
`.libPaths()`
points to "/usr/lib64/R/library" "/usr/share/R/library"

I was planning on creating a default `.Rprofile`  for all users which contains the line `.libPaths("/usr/share/R/library" )`. I think this will then default install software packages to the aforementioned directory.

Currently the write permissions to `usr/share/R/library/` is `drwxr-xr-x`. The first question would be should I all users to write to this directory or install R packages as root user?

On subsequent machines which I will install CentOS6, I was then thinking of using nfs to automount /usr/share/R/ on all other systems to point to margay:/usr/share/R/. SO I update the OS on machine 2 (`lynx`) and install R.How do I automount /usr/share/R/ on `lynx`to point to the equivalent directory on `margay`.

Does this seem like a sensible solution? If I install one new package on `margay`, would I be able to automatically run any R scripts which use this package on other machines? What are the pitfalls? Are the same versions of R necessary on all machines

---

Should I mount /usr/share/R/library on all other CentOS6 machines to point to /usr/share/R/library. Then if I install a new package as root on margay all other machines should see this new package? How do I do this if this is sensible

Comment: Why don't you just create your own repository?

Comment: @MichaelHampton. Just create a common directory for R packages and add to libPath()